# Two threads accessing the same char matrix alternatively

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to make a "X and O" game using threads. I use a char matrix[3][3] for my game table and I want the first thread to put "X" and after that to show the matrix and then the second threat to pun "O" and so on. How can I do this using threads?

```
public class ThreadExample implements Runnable {
private char[][] array;
private Semaphore ins, outs;
private int counter;

ThreadExample(Semaphore ins, Semaphore outs) {
    this.ins = ins;
    this.outs = outs;
    this.counter = 0;
    this.array = new char[3][3];
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        try {
            ins.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } // wait for permission to run
        print();
        playTurn();
        outs.release(); // allow another thread to run
    }
}

private void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private synchronized void playTurn() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int y;
    System.out.println("enter the x coord: ");
    x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the y coord: ");
    y = sc.nextInt();
    // sc.close();
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
        array[x][y] = 'X';
        counter++;
    } else {
        array[x][y] = 'O';
        counter++;
    }
}
```

}

And this is my main

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore a = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore b = new Semaphore(0);

    ThreadExample th1 = new ThreadExample(a, b);

    Thread tr1 = new Thread(th1);
    Thread tr2 = new Thread(th1);
    tr1.start();
    tr2.start();

}
```

}

This is my code so far but after the first x and y coord it stops.

Comment: use a thread mutex to synchronize the threads. what have you tried so far? :)

Comment: You don't need threads for this (in fact it makes things more complicated).

Comment: I know that I can do this without threads, but I have to do it with threads for learning purpose

Comment: then use a mutex as suggested by @xander

Comment: I don't get what you're trying in the code, you have 2 Semaphores, acquire one and release the other, that is pretty weird just use the same Semaphore for both threads!?

Comment: @xander it's not only the access to the shared resource that has to be synchronized, one also has to manage that the threads alternate each other.

Comment: @Henry yes, but in theory that should just happen automatically by itself if you start two threads and both use the same "mutex", one thread acquires it and the other waits, when the mutex is released the other thread should acquire it and the first is locked and so one.. I think :)

Comment: @xander that would only work "by chance" as it depends on the scheduling algorithm used.

Comment: Dude, this is great! I had to use only one semaphore and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: @Henry I don't think it's by chance in this case if you have a "slow" algorithm in the thread that runs every time, like user input that will block the thread anyway, I'm to lazy to write an actual example to prove your case, when the threads are fast running and competing with each other that might be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here, after the first 'x,y' both threads are waiting for the 'ins' Semaphore, and no one cares about the 'outs'.

You can fix it by remove 'outs' and use only 'ins'. Here you should double check, that how acquire is implemented. Does it grantee a queue or can a thread acquire it twice rarely?